# Python: delete sublists from a list based on first character of sublist item

Tags: python, list

I am trying to write a python 3 code for following function:

I have a list named Config,

```
Config = [[32, 31, 33, 34], [32, 42, 13, 33], [32, 42, 34, 44], [42, 42, 43, 44]]
```

This list has 4 sublists.

Now I want to get a new list from Config as follows (without first and fourth sublist),

```
ConfigRevised = [[32, 42, 13, 33], [32, 42, 34, 44]]
```

Because from each of the sublist it can be observed that:

1. [32, 31, 33, 34]: 1st character of each item in list are same [3, 3,
   3, 3] .
2. [32, 42, 13, 33]: 1st character of each item in list are not same
   [3, 2, 1, 3] .
3. [32, 42, 34, 44]: 1st character of each item in list are not same
   [3, 4, 3, 4] .
4. [42, 42, 43, 44]: 1st character of each item in list are same [4, 4,
   4, 4].

Now, I want to delete sublist 1 and sublist 4, because first character of sublist items are same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Config = [[32, 31, 33, 34], [32, 42, 13, 33], [32, 42, 34, 44], [42, 42, 43, 44]]
new_results = [i for i in Config if len({str(b)[0] for b in i}) > 1]
```

Output:

```
[[32, 42, 13, 33], [32, 42, 34, 44]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create new one from old one then:

```
Config = [[32, 31, 33, 34], [32, 42, 13, 33], [32, 42, 34, 44], [42, 42, 43, 44],[11,22,33,44]]

checker=[]
for j,i in enumerate(Config):
    check_data=[list(str(j))[0] for j in i]
    datar=[check_data for m in check_data if check_data.count(m)>2]
    if not datar:
        checker.append(i)
print(checker)
```

If you want to delete then you can try:

```
Config = [[32, 31, 33, 34], [32, 42, 13, 33], [32, 42, 34, 44], [42, 42, 43, 44],[11,22,33,44]]

checker={}
for j,i in enumerate(Config):
    check_data=[list(str(j))[0] for j in i]
    datar=[check_data for m in check_data if check_data.count(m)>2]
    if datar:

        checker[j]=1
    else:
        checker[j]=0

for value,del_value in checker.items():
    if del_value==1:
        del Config[value]
print(Config)
```

output:

```
[[32, 42, 13, 33], [32, 42, 34, 44], [42, 42, 43, 44]]
```